# Protecting images in header and footer areas in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, headers, footers, protected

We're trying to create Word templates based on our corporate identity but we need to prevent changes to the images (size, position, etc.) in the header and footer areas of the documents. Is there a way to do that while allowing users to create their text documents with relative freedom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the Restrict Editing button on the Developer tab.  The Developer tab isn't visible by default--if you don't see it, the option to display it is under File | Options | Customize Ribbon ([Microsoft Support article with steps](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)).

1. Format your headers and footers the way you want them.
2. Select **Restrict Editing** on the Developer tab.
3. Under **2. Editing restrictions**, select **No changes (Read Only).**
4. Select the body of the document. Under **Exceptions**, check **Everyone.** (If you have formatting marks displayed, you'll see a gray I-bar appear in the document.)
5. Under **3. Start enforcement**, select **Yes, Start enforcing protection**. Enter a password if you want one, or leave it blank for no password. (Not selecting a password means that employees can remove the protections if they're that bound and determined to mess with your formatting, and if they know how.)